# how access elements of a div using this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to access element of this dynamically created div. This is the html

```
<div id="uploader">
<div class="row uploadDoc">
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="docErr">Please upload valid file</div>
    <!--error-->
    <div class="fileUpload btn btn-orange">
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/136/136549.svg" class="icon">
        <span class="upl" id="upload">Upload document</span>
        <input type="file" class="upload up" id="up" onchange="readURL(this);">
    </div>
    <!-- btn-orange -->
</div>
<!-- col-3 -->
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="document_name" placeholder="Document Name">
</div>
<!--col-8-->
<div class="col-sm-1"><a class="btn-check"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
<!-- col-1 -->
```

this is the part that is dynamically created

```
 <div class="row uploadDoc">
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="docErr">Please upload valid file</div>
    <!--error-->
    <div class="fileUpload btn btn-orange"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/136/136549.svg" class="icon"><span class="upl" id="upload3">Upload document</span><input type="file" class="upload up" id="up" onchange="readURL(this);"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Doc3note" name="" placeholder="Note"></div>
<div class="col-sm-1"><a class="btn-check"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
```

I have a file upload handler called readURL()

```
 function readURL(input) { }
```

what I want to get is the id of a specific div, so I tried this and many other unsuccessful methods

```
   function readURL(input) {  
    console.log($(input).closest('.col-sm-8').find(".form-control").attr('id')); 
  }
```

I hope my explanation is clear, I want to get the id of class="col-sm-8" on file upload. how can implement this?

Comment: `$(input).closest('.row').find(".form-control").attr('id')`

Comment: You need to traverse further up: `.closest('.uploadDoc').find('.form-control')`

Comment: Your div with `'.col-sm-8'` doesn't have an id.

Comment: did u try to bind it to body context as $(body).on('click','.dynamicEle', function(e) {
        alert('tst');
    }); if u want to assign click event to dynamicly added dom element

Answer (score 0):

Passing the id `up` *(uploadFile input)*

**Execute this:** `$(input).parent().parent().next()`

Look at this code snippet

```js
function readURL(input) {
  console.log('Id of Div: ' + $(input).parent().parent().next().attr('id'));
  console.log('Id of form-control input: ' + $(input).parent().parent().next().find(".form-control").attr('id'));
  
}

readURL('#up');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row uploadDoc">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="docErr">Please upload valid file</div>
    <!--error-->
    <div class="fileUpload btn btn-orange"> <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/136/136549.svg" class="icon"><span class="upl" id="upload3">Upload document</span><input type="file" class="upload up" id="up" onchange="readURL(this);"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" id='div(col-sm-8)'><input type="text" class="form-control" id="Doc3note" name="" placeholder="Note"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1"><a class="btn-check"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></div>
```

## Resources

- [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)